# How jQuery LoadingOverlay supports IE browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I visit this site can support IE8+.
But when I download https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gasparesganga-jquery-loading-overlay@2.1.7/dist/loadingoverlay.min.js, it will not work in my webpage.

in my jsp

```
 <!--[if lt IE 10]>
<script src="<%=path%>/js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>

<script>
    if (!Array.prototype.indexOf)
    {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elt /*, from*/)
    {
    var len = this.length >>> 0;

    var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
    from = (from < 0)
         ? Math.ceil(from)
         : Math.floor(from);
    if (from < 0)
      from += len;

    for (; from < len; from++)
    {
      if (from in this &&
          this[from] === elt)
        return from;
    }
    return -1;
    };
    }
</script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=path%>/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=path%>/js/loading/loadingoverlay.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.LoadingOverlay("show");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: do you get an error in the browser console perhaps?

Comment: There is no error in IE browser 
Valid in Google Chrome

Comment: Does adding this work? <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: if there's no error, then what does "it will not work in my webpage" even mean (to be honest, I'm surprised IE8 even has a console) - can you confirm that the html5shiv is even loaded? and finally - do you even need to support such a dinosaur?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm Chinese, my English is not very good, maybe I didn't speak clearly .  html5shiv is loaded

Comment: not sure what your ethnicity has to do with anything - you did speak clearly, without giving much information - the phrase "doesn't work" provides absolutely no information to work with, regardless of language or ethnicity